# get html file from href and load it into the page using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this menu:

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-left" aria- labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

  <a class="dropdown-item tuning-selection" id="guitar_standard" href="tunings/guitar_standard.html">Guitar(Standard)</a>

  <a class="dropdown-item tuning-selection" id="guitar_drop_d" href="tunings/guitar_drop_d.html">Guitar(Drop D) </a>

  <a class="dropdown-item tuning-selection" id="bass_standard" href="tunings/bass_standard.html">Bass Standard</a>

  <a class="dropdown-item tuning-selection" id="mandolin_standard" href="tunings/mandolin_standard.html">Mandolin</a>

</div>
```

How could I load those HTML files into a separate div (with no page refresh) via Vanilla JS? I know jQuery is easier but I want to learn how to do it with Vanilla JS.

Comment: If you search for "javascript ajax" you should come up with the standard implementation in plain js. Jquery is nice as it takes care of certain browser specific details that makes the long form messy. Alternatively you can also use iframes. What specifically are you looking for and what have you tried?

Comment: Is `"guitar_standard.html"` an entire HTML document or a document fragment?

Comment: its a fragment, its just a div with h1 tags inside of it. as is all of the other files.

Comment: The linked duplicate has answer that show how to make Ajax requests and load the result into a particular element on the current page. Combine that with a simple click handler on your anchor elements that uses `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default anchor navigation and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: You can also avoid `innerHTML` by using  a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) on the fetched text.

Comment: @nnnnnn AJAX is not necessary to meet requirement.

Comment: @guest271314  Without Ajax, how would you load content into a specific DIV in response to clicking on a menu anchor, *without page refresh*?

Comment: @nnnnnn Import the document fragment when `document` is loaded using `<link rel="import">`, clone nodes of the `document`, append the cloned nodes an existing or dynamically created element.

Comment: @guest271314 - That's an interesting solution, but doesn't it load all of the content every time, even though the user may not ever click all of the links? Most people looking for the bass tuning probably won't want the mandolin tuning.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, all of the content is loaded. Loading of content can be adjusted, with usage of related attributes or other processes, if that is the requirement. The approach is essentially a  single page application, though still requesting external content. The pattern could also proceed in the opposite direction, with all necessary content embedded in the HTML itself; and possibly capable of self-modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `"import"` to load the document fragments before `click` on element in `document.body`, and set content of `<div>` to cloned element of `link.import` `#document`.

```html
<link rel="import" href="data:text/html,<div><h1>guitar standard</h1></div>" id="guitar_standard">
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-left" aria- labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

  <a class="dropdown-item tuning-selection" href="#guitar_standard">Guitar(Standard)</a>

</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  const content = document.getElementById("content");
  const links = document.links;
  const imports = document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=import]");
  for (const link of links) {
    link.onclick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        const clone = document.querySelector(e.target.hash).import
                      .querySelector("div").cloneNode(true);
        content.appendChild(clone);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, there is this polyfill which uses AJAX to load the external documents.

Comment: @Kaiido Did not notice AJAX was used at the `.js`. Do you suggest Answer be deleted due to lack of support at Firefox or other browsers?

Comment: No not at all, still a good thing which will hopefully come with support in the future. But IMO AJAX still worths it.